# Remote connection to the server through VSCode Remote SSH

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, vscode-remote-ssh

```
Host Jumpserver
  HostName aaa.top
  Port 1111
  User wumingxu#@USER#111-222-333-444
```

The above is my ssh config file. My User contains #, so when connecting to a remote server, it was mistakenly treated as a comment, causing connection errors. Is there any way to avoid this problem?

I have tried to escape the # character through \ # t, but it doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue, and spend painful minutes my boss was waiting for me.

I solved it by downgrading from 1.86 vscode to 1.85

Download this.

https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_85

error shows:

```
remote host may not meet vscode server prerequisites for glibc and libstdc++
```

more details here:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/9467

Comment: I have tried this method, but it still cannot solve the problem